# Filter database and remove duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a Mysql database with 1200000 records and it is holding albums from famous artists. The only problem is, there are duplicates but the only duplicate field is not the primary key but the title. Is there an easy script in PHP to remove the unnecesary?

Answer (score 2):

Delete a row if there `exists` another row with same title but a lower id.

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select * from tablename t2
              where t2.title = t1.title
                and t2.id < t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct tablename .*
  FROM tablename as tb1
  join tablename as tb2
 WHERE tb1.title = tb2.title
   and tb1.id < tb2.id
```

it might help you to fetch non duplicate records

for deleting duplicate records

```
DELETE tablename 
  FROM tablename as tb1
  join tablename as tb2
 WHERE tb1.title = tb2.title
   and tb1.id < tb2.id
```